# Users names not resolving on one server but do on another

Tags: 2013, active-directory, people-picker

I have a 4 server Farm, 1DB, 1 App and 2 WFE's

I've noticed that if I am on WFE1 and I go onto a site and try to add someone to a Permissions Group all is fine. As soon as you start typing the users name in it starts to appear and resolves as you would expect.

However, on WFE2 and APP Server, the same name being added to the same permissions group does not resolve. Also, as I type no names start to appear.

Also, if I use the same account but not on a server I cannot administer Permissions as the names do not resolve.

Frankly, I'm stumped. It's the same process on the same server farm. Something must have gone wrong during the setup but I'm at a loss to know what.

Anyone with any advice on where to start with this one would be most appreciated. Thanks. Dan

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing seems like communication issue between FE2 and the domain controller. I would do following steps to nail down the problem.

1. As first step I would run PSConfig to see does it resolve the issue.
2. Check the Security Token Service on that server and ensure it is running (you can navigate to it from IIS manger)
3. Test the ports that people picker needs, there is this nifty tool to do just that: https://github.com/Nauplius/PeoplePickerPortTester
4. Review the event viewer log System and Application for any suspicious events. Open event viewer see last errors, recreate issue do you get any new events?
5. Second step would be to check ULS Logs. Grab ULS log viewer open filter by errors only and recreate the issue (by trying to add user)
6. If none of those would point to the culprit I would use process monitor from system internals to see if the IIS process gets any 'Denied' results.

Comment: Marek, thanks for the suggestions. I've tried a few of these already but I'll go through the list and check again. Dan

Comment: When you type the name in the People Picker do you get any error? I had once a problem with timing on the servers and it was reporting 'We couldn't connect to the server' or something similar.

Comment: After much digging I finally found the solution. The users that were not being found were FBA users. I checked the Web Config for the connection and it was there on WFE1 but not on WFE2. Added the connection to WFE2 and it started working

This Technet was instrumental in providing answers :-

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/

Thanks Marek for your help with this one - Dan

Answer (score 0):

After much digging I finally found the solution. The users that were not being found were FBA users. I checked the Web Config for the connection and it was there on WFE1 but not on WFE2. Added the connection to WFE2 and it started working

This Technet was instrumental in providing answers :-

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ptsblog/2013/09/20/configuring-sharepoint-2013-forms-based-authentication-with-sqlmembershipprovider/

Thanks Marek for your help with this one - Dan